# How dual gyroscopes can be used to remove gyro drift?

Tags: filter, measurement, gyroscope

I need to measure yaw/heading/azimuth correctly.

Now, I have done with gyro with very strong filtering and the results are very low yaw drift and even when there is perfect calibration then there is no drift but angle measured is not perfect and if there is to and fro motion then there is a difference in angle from reference point become increases

Now, what will be the effect of using dual gyro even with three gyros? can I have better results by using multigyro. If yes then how and also suggest any research paper, fusion algoritm or math, etc.

**Note:** My environment is highly influenced by electromagnetic waves. So, there is no option for the magnetometer.

Thanks

Comment: What error is acceptable? (You won't ever get zero). There are a number of ways to compensate for gyro drift without a magnetometer.

Comment: at max 2 degree error will be fine

Comment: Gyro doesn't output angle (degrees), rather rate of change - deg/s; rad/s

Comment: Accelerometer compensation is quite effective.

Comment: @peterSmith Accelerometer compensation for YAW?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič yes I have integrated it to get angle

Comment: You will never get an angle by means of gyro signal integration, no such gyro exist yet.

Comment: As @PeterSmith said yes, YAW also. You get compensated it, but you won't be able to measure the angle, nor the position would be repeatable.

Comment: You seem awfully secretive about what this actually is. What is the application and where are these strong magnetic fields coming from? You can still use a compass in strong magnetic fields under some circumstances but you have provided no detail. If you truly cannot then there are alternatives but we need more application info.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have to measure antenna azimuth with the accuracy of 2 deg. This is telecom antenna. So, How can I use magnetometer here?

Comment: @AnsHafeez Much detail is still missing. We are not mind readers. Where are the strong magnetic fields coming from? Are they static or dynamic? How strong? Do you have mechanical access? Is the antenna permanently static? Portable? Mobile? Manual? Motorized? These are the kind of details missing because they tell us whether other options such as solar trackers, encoders, soft/hard iron magnetometer calibration, or magnetic compass to index an encoder before power-up are possible. A permanent static fixture like a radio telescope, portable antenna stand, and car do not track yaw the same way.

Comment: @DKNguyen Actually I don't have much information and don't have access to site right now. Antenna is statically placed on telecom tower. My bottleneck is YAW :(

Answer (score 1):

While you can fuse the measurements from multiple IMUs on a rigid body to get diminishing returns on state-estimation, there is no way to cancel out the gyro drift doing this *alone*. Integrating angular velocity to estimate yaw is fraught and yaw estimates will deteriorate within seconds.

Briefly, you can correct for gyro drift by fusing with yaw measurements from a magnetometer. Kalman filter based approaches do this by including the gyro-bias as states to be estimated. What you get is known as an Attitude and Heading Reference System (AHRS). One method for doing this is with the [Madgwick Filter](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5621018/) - if you're fooling around with Arduino by chance, there are numerous examples/demos online.